# HTACCESS - specific redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following situation:
A website was created with the URL's as follows:

```
http://example.com/city1/product

http://example.com/city2/product

http://example.com/city3/product
```

Now, these three sites will become a single site.

The URLs remain exactly the same, but as follows:

```
http://example.com/product
```

Could someone help me formulate an HTACCESS to redirect the contents of city1, 2 and 3 to the root of the domain?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like the following:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/(?:city1|city2|city3)/(product)$ /$1
```